# 'module' object has no attribute 'commit_unless_managed'

Tags: django, django-tests, django-nose

I am using django 1.8 and django-nose 1.4 and while I run

```
REUSE_DB=1 python manage.py test
```

It shows error message

```
'module' object has no attribute 'commit_unless_managed'
```

What may the the solution ?

Comment: Upgrade or replace whatever is using that, that method was removed in 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

solution is to remove the reuse flag for at least one call. your previous build broke the db and it needs to reset it.